# What font is used on Roya's "Samsara" album cover?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I've been searching for this font *Roya* (texture not included of course) and still no luck!

[image: Roya's "Samsara" album cover]

What is it? (or one that is similar?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freska](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/activesphere/freska/) designed by [Ronnie Dela Cruz](https://www.myfonts.com/person/Ronnie_Dela_Cruz/), 2013, via myfonts.com

[image]

[image]